# Act Warning When Using MUI Popover

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I am having a hard time getting a component to render without any act warnings from react.  Here is the component that I am testing.  It contains a TextField and a Popover.  The idea is that the parent component controls when and what the Popover displays.

```
const PopoverContainer = (props: TextFieldWithPopoverProps) => {
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
    const anchorRef = React.useRef(null);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setAnchorEl(anchorRef.current);
    }, [anchorRef]);

    return (
        <>
            <TextField type="text" ref={anchorRef}/>
            <Popover id={props.popperId} open={props.open} sx={{ zIndex: 1001 }} anchorEl={anchorEl}>
                <Paper>
                    {props.renderedChild}
                </Paper>
            </Popover>
        </>
    );
};
```

And here is the test.

```
test('should open popover', async () => {
    const { rerender } = render(<PopoverContainer open={false} popperId="popper-id" renderedChild={renderInnerPopover()} />);

    expect(screen.queryByText('Hello World!')).toBe(null);

    await userEvent.type(await screen.findByRole('textbox'), 'HELLO');

    rerender(<PopoverContainer open={true} popperId="popper-id" renderedChild={renderInnerPopover()} />);

    expect(await screen.findByText('Hello World!'));
});

const renderInnerPopover = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            Hello World!
        </div>
    );
};
```

And here is an example of a few of the act warnings that are reported.

**Warning: An update to ForwardRef(FormControl) inside a test was not wrapped in act(...)

Warning: An update to ForwardRef(Popover) inside a test was not wrapped in act(...)**

Act warnings are always on the rerender call.  I have tried putting act() around the rerender call and the type event but neither fixes the problem.  I have also tried not setting the TextField which does prevent the act warnings but of course that defeats what the component is trying to accomplish.

Comment: You need to wrap the first render too.

Comment: You've got a use effect updating state on mount. Do what I said and it will work. This question gets asked all the time...

Comment: I tried wrapping both render and rerender in an act() but I am still getting the warnings.  I did also try changing the type event to not be awaited, which strangely did allow the test to pass without any warnings.  However, my eslint is now complaining about floating promises.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else running into a similar issue.  I swapped userEvent for fireEvent for the typing event.  Not sure if its a bug with the recent changes to userEvent or something that I am doing but it did resolve the problem.

```
test('should open popover', async () => {
    const { rerender } = render(<PopoverContainer open={false} popperId="popper-id" renderedChild={renderInnerPopover()} />);

    expect(screen.queryByText('Hello World!')).toBe(null);

    // await userEvent.type(await screen.findByRole('textbox'), 'HELLO');
    fireEvent.change(await screen.findByRole('textbox'), { target: { value: 'HELLO' } });

    rerender(<PopoverContainer open={true} popperId="popper-id" renderedChild={renderInnerPopover()} />);

    expect(await screen.findByText('Hello World!'));
});

const renderInnerPopover = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            Hello World!
        </div>
    );
};
```